# Perl script clarification

Tags: perl

I have the following perl script and observed that the statement at line number 5 is taking 30 sec to execute.  I do not have any clue how to investigate why its taking that much time.

Can you please suggest me on what could be the reason?

```perl
sub parse {
   my $self = shift;
   my $parse_options = $self->get_options(@_);
   my $method = $self->can('_parse_systemid');
   return $method->($self, $parse_options->{Source}{SystemId});  # takes 30 s
}
```

Comment: This does seem like long time. What is your hardware setup?

Comment: Line 5 is a subroutine call. Looks like it might be returned from the `can()` subroutine. What a mess.

Comment: Hi Ham, I am executing this perl script on Linux platform.

Comment: Hi TLP, Script  is working fine but only thing i could see is its taking more time i.e. 30 sec for execution and i am trying find out what could be the root cause.

Comment: Yes, you already said that. And I said the answer lies not in this subroutine, but in the subroutine called `can`. We do not know why `can` returns code that takes a long time to execute, because it is arbitrary code. You need to show the relevant code for us to know.

Comment: @TLP How can the problem be `can`? He said line number 5, which is `return $method->($self.....)`, which is really just `return $self->_parse_systemid( $parse_options->..... )`.  So what is taking 30 seconds is whatever goes on inside of `_parse_systemid`, right?

Comment: @DavidO Well, no, the subroutine called is `$self->can( ... )`. The argument is the string `_parse_systemid`. Presumably, this returns a code reference or an object which is then used by the next line.

Comment: There is also a missing semi-colon on line 4, just noticed.

Comment: Well, presumably, because `$self->_parse_systemid()` is doing a lot of work. But without knowing what it's doing I can't see how we can be any more help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The code you provided:

```
sub parse {
   my $self = shift;
   my $parse_options = $self->get_options(@_);
   my $method = $self->can('_parse_systemid')
   return $method->($self, $parse_options->{Source}{SystemId});  # takes 30 s
}
```

Can be refactored to look like this:

```
sub parse {
  my $self = shift;
  my $parse_options = $self->get_options(@_);
  return $self->_parse_systemid( $parse_options->{Source}{SystemId} ); # Still takes 30s.
}
```

In either case, if `_parse_systemid` isn't a member function of the object referred to by $self, the script dies, so the use of `can` is probably useless.

Anyway, the code that is taking a long time to execute still takes a long time in the refactored code.  This line would still be a problem for you:

```
return $self->_parse_systemid( $parse_options->{Source}{SystemId} ); # Still takes 30s.
```

Let's refactor that a bit just to make it clearer:

```
my $systemid = $parse_options->{Source}{SystemId};
my $rv = $self->_parse_systemid( $systemid ); # Still takes 30s.
return $rv;
```

Now it becomes pretty clear that what is taking 30 seconds is the call to `$self->_parse_systemid()`.  So you need to be looking at what happens inside the `_parse_systemid` method of the class referred to by `$self`.

It might be very useful to invoke the assistance of [Devel::NYTProf](http://search.cpan.org/~timb/Devel-NYTProf-5.06/lib/Devel/NYTProf.pm), which will allow you to drill down into `_parse_systemid` to see what is taking so long there.

We cannot provide a definitive answer because the code posted doesn't contain the problem.  As such, strictly speaking, it's an unanswerable question, as asked.  However, I do believe that the recommendations given in this answer will put you on the right track.

**Update**: kjpirs mentioned this in a comment, and is correct:  `_parse_systemid` probably comes from XML::SAX::PurePerl or XML::LibXML::SAX.  By convention, subroutines that start with an underscore are intended to be private to a class or object.  Your usage is risky; when you use functions that are not part of the public API for an object or class, all bets are off -- you've ventured out on your own.

Comment: _parse_systemid is found in XML::SAX::PurePerl and XML::LibXML::SAX, and I think in both cases calling them causes the input file to be parsed entirely: that's why it takes so long.  (Also, by convention, methods/functions that begin with underscore are for internal use only and are usually not published so the authors can change them without notice: beware of using them!)

Comment: Yes, I almost mentioned that methods beginning with underscore are conventionally intended to be private, but then realized that it was possible that the OP's "`parse`" method was already a member of the same class as `_parse_systemid`.  So good catch on recognizing that it comes from XML::SAZ::PurePerl / XML::LibXML::SAX; now it is totally appropriate to mention that functions starting with underscore are conventionally intended to be private.

Comment: After your analysis. I checked my perl scripts  and it is using SAX parser only.

Can you please let us know if you have suggestion on any workaround  for this issue?

Comment: I have updated SAX parser  to latest i.e. XML-SAX-0.99 but still i could see the same issue.

Can any one please suggest me any work around ?

Comment: How big is your XML document?

Comment: Hi David,
The XML file size is 5 MB , almost 4700 tags are available.

Comment: Maybe an XML::Twig solution would be more appropriate, so that you can process in chunks.

Comment: Can you please describe more on XML::Twig ? how we can replace SAX parser with XML::Twig